# PHP Storm Magic Method Access Error on persistence->parameters

Tags: php, phalcon

When i code phalcon with phpstorm i have one particular error i cannot figure out how to resolve. I like to see the green check at the top of each page to indicate there are no issues but this error is preventing the green checkmark shown.

So this is what causes the error:

```
$this->persistent->parameters = null;
```

How can i alter that code to prevent the PHP Storm error:
Field accessed via magic method

I know its a bit picky but would love to solve this

Answer (score 2):

Use `@property` PhpDoc construction. Example:

[image]

It's also gives autocomplete to magic properties. Always use all available inspections.

Comment: thank you but i am struggling to apply it. I tried: @property string $persistent but now it no longer highlights persistent and instead highlights parameters and says that the field was declared dynamically

Comment: Try `@property Persistent $persistent`. You can't use `persistent->parameters` on string. Class Persistent should have right PhpDoc too.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "Notify about access to a field via magic method".

You can find this setting under Project Settings -> Inspections -> PHP -> Undefined -> Undefined field.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download the framework code from the devtoolos on Github and Include it in PHP Storm. You can either add it as library dependency or simple paste it in the file explorer of your project.

https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/tree/master/ide/2.0.7/Phalcon

It should have all the required PHP Doc